# Is it possible to recover a file that was opened with FileMode.Create or FileMode.Truncate

Tags: c#

We have a bit of a situation, where some important files were opened using FileMode.Create, which is essentially FileMode.Trancate, that left all opened files with 0 bytes length.

```
System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(filepath, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
```

Do you think it's possible to recover those files assuming nothing was written over them? I assume the header is good and the data should be somewhere there too, but I don't know enough about how streams are written to the disk.

Comment: When you have the files on a hard disk where you have physical access to, you could try the tool [GetDataBack](http://www.runtime.org) or similar. I made good experiences in recovering deleted files. Don't know how it is when you overwrite with File.Create, headers could be destroyed. When files are on network, ask you administrator.

Comment: We tried similar tools, like from Kroll Ontrack, but it didn't find the files. Supposedly finding deleted files is very easy because they are not really deleted from the disk, but when a file is considred to be overwritten, like with our case, those tools fail. They might be able to find files but without folders or names, which makes them pretty useles, especially if there a lot of them. I thought if I know exactly how the files where overwritten, I might be able to recover them somehow.

Comment: Essentially the files *are* deleted, and have been replaced with new files of the same name. If you deleted those new files you'd essentially have the same situation as if you deleted the originals from the start. So, good luck finding them among the rest of the nameless files, basically. The file *contents* should still be recoverable assuming nothing else was written to the *volume* (not merely the files). Associating those contents with the original file name is another matter.

Comment: Restore from your most recent backup. You *do* backup all *important files*, don't you?